# Custom HTML,CSS,JS,PHP Pages in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress. I am used to make websites from scratch.
I am currently working on a wordpress template (Astra).
I need to make a custom page using HTML,CSS,JS,Php from scratch and add it to my wordpress pages.. How can I do it?
I've google it and saw many approaches but didn't get anyone of it.. Some suggested to make a Parent/Child related pages but I don't know ..

Can I just put a .php file in the directory and make a link between it and wordpress pages?
How can I link css/js pages with them also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Create a .php file with all the html css JS and php code. on Top add comment inside your file

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Custom Page HTML */
```

and then create a new page and Select new created Template and publish that page.
you can create this file inside your theme folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a normal page in wordpress then in the back end editor you can edit the html raw. I usually use my JavaScript inside my html. As for the css you can edit that by going to the page you created when logged in, then clicking customize. There should be a additional css option where you can edit the styling.